# block some pages with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I used to have php site with some keywords in file name like this

domain.com/?keyword-one,23
domain.com/?another-keyword,43
domain.com/?one-more-keyword,23
and so on

the problem is that I have an index.html file now and the above pages are still works because of that ? after the first / because the server is attaching those files as domain.com/index.html?keyword-one,23

is there any way to show error 410 gone using htaccess?

I used RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [R=404,L,NC] and it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got it to work.

RewriteRule ^/?$ - [R=410,L,NC]

Comment: Now only one problem left, I cannot domain.com cuz it wont open default index.html page